# What is a constant when talking about asymptotic bounds

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

For example I have the function in Johnsonbaugh's book:
$$n\log_{2}(n/4)$$
and it concludes that $$\log_{2}n!=\Omega(n\log_{2}n)$$
My question is what exactly is a constant in this case? Are constants positive integers? Real numbers? And in this case what is the constant in $$n\log_{2}(n/4)$$

Answer (score 0):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates)

$$\log_{2}n! \sim \log_{2}\left(\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)\sim n\log_2 (n/e)=n(\log_2 n-\log_2 e)$$

and

$$n\log_{2}(n/4)=n(\log_2 n-\log_2 4)$$

Comment: That didn't really answer the question, I wanted to know what the value of constant C was

Comment: @TianPeng It seems the constant is $C=1$ indeed.

Comment: But it's not 1, how did you arrive to the conclusion that it's 1?